# how to remove error message in mac relate to rJava

Tags: java, r, rjava

I have install rJava package in R and I also install Java 64 bit on my mac but somehow I am keep getting error message when I try to load rJava package.

```
library(rJava)
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried all sort of things that I can possibly do.
I tried to insert `sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib` 
in terminal

I also tried `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre')`

```
dyn.load(paste0(system2('/usr/libexec/java_home',stdout = TRUE), '/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'))
dir(paste0(system2('/usr/libexec/java_home',stdout=TRUE)))
```

but they all doesn't work for me
Keep getting same error message as above.
can someone plz help me.
Thanks

Comment: (a) From a Terminal prompt, what does `R CMD javareconf` show (i.e. paste the output of that into a code block); (b) does `library(rJava)` work from an R console prompt in the Terminal? (c) if (b) is true, then is the failure only within RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on my Mac. For Java 9 the path is different compared to the one you posted.

```
sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

And also below to update R.

```
MY_R_VERSION=$(Rscript -e "cat(with(R.version, sprintf('%s.%s', major, substring(minor, 1, 1))))")
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libjvm.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/$MY_R_VERSION/Resources/lib/
```